# Starting a method when a value goes outside its bounds

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, methods, frequency, between

I am coming up with a little trouble with the following code. Essentially I am trying to start a method whenever the value goes between 45 and 46 and subsequently goes outside of these bounds.

```
if(value >= 45 && value < 46){
    if(value >= 46 && value < 45){
        [self updateTwo];
    }
    else{
        [frequencyImage setImage:A3StaveSemiQuaver];
    }
}
```

I've used NSLog to try and debug this problem and i've found that the second if statement is not firing.

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusion, I think the best way to explain this that "value" relates to the frequency (in Hz) of sound from the device's microphone. It is constantly checking the frequency and updating "value". I want to find a way for a method to be fired off if the value becomes 45 and then subsequently becomes a value other than 45. For instance say value is 25, 44, 45, 10 - I want the method to fire on the 10. I'm not the best at explaining it, apologies for that! Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: How can the second if block run if a value for the first if block has to be more than 45 and less than 46 and then your nested if block requires the value to be greater than 46 and less than 45... that would never happen?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what it is you're looking for... so you want the value to be between 45 and 46?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If the value is greater than or equal to 45 and less than 46 can ONLY be 45. The next statement is checking for a value that is greater than or equal to 46 (we already know it's 45 from above so this is a fail) and also conditionally you're asking for value to be less than 45. you can never have a number greater than 46 but less than 45. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @evan.stoddard No problem :) - I'm not sure what jamiemaison is trying to achieve. If he replies I'm sure we can help him :)

Comment: @evan.stoddard & latenitecoder Sorry for the confusion- I've added a bit more information to the question so it's a little clearer! Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

your `2nd if` statement is inside the first `if`

so take a look at your `first if`  which match for number which is 45 only (check it).
Your `second if` which will trigger right after the `first if` and only if `first if` is `true` which means your number is 45 -> will always be `false` because it's statement matches number >= 46 (only when > = 46 it returns `true` , but your number can't be >= 46 , if it passed the `first if` it must be only 45 ).